# External Table not getting updated from parquet files written by spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am using spark streaming to write the aggregated output as parquet files to the hdfs using SaveMode.Append. I have an external table created like :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists rolluptable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet
OPTIONS (
  path "hdfs:////"
);
```

I had an impression that in case of external table the queries should fetch the data from newly parquet added files also. But, seems like the newly written files are not being picked up.

Dropping and recreating the table every time works fine but not a solution.

Please suggest how can my table have the data from newer files also.

Comment: @SambitTripathy..yes. you can use refresh table <tablename>

Comment: is it possible to write data like this to hdfs location ?        pr.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("parquet").option("path", "hdfs://nnnt/apps/hive/warehouse/rea.db/sample_movcsvfin/").option("checkpointLocation", "/user/sa/sparkCheckpoint").partitionBy("year").trigger(ProcessingTime("5 seconds")).start()

Answer (score 7):

Are you reading those tables with spark?
if so, spark caches parquet tables metadata (since schema discovery can be expensive)

To overcome this, you have 2 options:

1. Set the config `spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata` to `false`
2. refresh the table before the query: `sqlContext.refreshTable("my_table")`

See here for more details: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion

Comment: I am currently running refresh table <table_name> from the beeline client in a bash script which seems to be working.

Comment: I have tried all the three below commands. It doesn't seem to work for me. spark.sqlContext().clearCache();        spark.sqlContext().setConf("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata","false"); spark.conf().set("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata",false);

Comment: spark.catalog.refreshTable("mytable") works for me